# Execute SQL Task:error Executing the Query Create table already exist:SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want to create a excel file dynamically so

I create a variable CreateExcel and written a query to create a Table

```
CREATE TABLE `BOL` (
    `CustomerPO` LongText,
    `ShippingNum` LongText,
    `BOL` LongText,
    `PRO` LongText,
    `SSCC_Code` LongText,
    `LineType` LongText,
    `SKU` LongText,
    `Row_Number` LongText,
    `UPCCode` LongText,
 `Location` LongText,    `Quantity` LongText
)
```

At the first time The Package execute successfully when i run afterwords
i am getting error

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "CREATE TABLE BOL (
>   CustomerPO LongText,
>       `S..." failed with the following error: "Table BOL already exists.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
>   "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,
>   or connection not established correctly.

Comment: before creating a table you have to check whether it exists in the database. IF exists drop the table and re-create it

Answer (score 2):

before creating a `Table` you have to check whether it exists in the `Database`. IF exists `drop` the `Table` and re-create it

```
IF EXISTS
(
 SELECT 1
 FROM SYS.TABLES 
 WHERE TYPE = 'U'
 AND NAME = 'BOL'
)
BEGIN
     DROP TABLE BOL
END
GO
```

Comment: I am Creating an Excel file by using ShipmentNumber+TimeStamp,In my Previous Package it will run Sucessfully without droping the Table

Comment: So are you creating an Excel table in Execute SQL Task rather than creating a db table? If so you need to : 1) Set the project properties to delay validation 2) Have a file system task to delete the Excel file prior to the SQL Task that creates it. I have more info on this if you want!

Comment: @MigueIH does creating table in db is a better approach?

Comment: Hi @bmsqldev! I agree! I'm just trying to clarify what the user is doing. It looks to me from the question that they are trying to create an excel workbook with defined headings (i.e. a table in excel) rather than a db table.

Comment: @MigueLH can i get some suggestions like this from you regarding ssis. I am new to it.

Comment: Hi @bmsqldev. There's a good guide to creating excel output here [http://oakdome.com/programming/SSIS_DataTransform.php

Comment: @MiguLH. Thanks for the link. Is there any website with sample datawarehouse data for ssis practice? I mean with real time scenarios

Comment: I taken only one OledbSource and witten a Query select 
ShipmentID, cast(ShipmentID as nvarchar(9))+'_'+convert(nvarchar(10),getdate(),112)+'_'+replace(convert(nvarchar(8),getdate(),114),':','_') FileName
from
Get_Shipping_Data gsd
left join CartonInfo ci ON gsd.ShipmentID collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = ci.ShipmentNumber
where ci.CRT_ExportFlag='1' and ci.ShipmentLocation='NYWT'
group by ShipmentID

Comment: and uses a Recordeset and store the Values into a Varible object and next i taken a ForEach Loop Container in that i Taken Excute Sql Task and made a excel connection and written a sql query using a varible like CreateExcel